# Can't dump the symbols of my native library : loadDataForPdb and loadDataFromExe failed

Tags: android, google-breakpad

I copied the sample of Google breakpad for Android and added it to my project. I had first a problem to get the minidumps (I was triggering SIGSEGV errors but nothing was written on my SD card). I finally managed to get some minidumps (I don't really know how but that's not my main problem).

My problem is that I can't dump the symbols of my native libraries, it says the following error message :

```
dump_syms.exe libcppinterface.so > libcppinterface.so.sym
loadDataForPdb and loadDataFromExe failed
Open failed
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: try this  ./configure --build=i686-linux --host=i686-pc-cygwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Breakpad tools are not very cross-platform friendly. You need to build dump_syms on a Linux machine in order to get a dump_syms binary that can read ELF/DWARF and produce debug symbols from your Android binaries. The Windows dump_syms.exe is only used for dumping symbols from MSVC-produced PDB files.